# Did we ever see Enterprise-D's arboretum?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

It seems they mention the arboretum many times.   Apparently Miles O'Brien proposed to Keiko there.   Barclay and Troi go for a walk there.   A tree is beamed to the Crystalline Entity from there.   But if I recall, it is always off screen.

Do we ever see it?   If not, why not?   How big is it?

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR: Yes, the Arboretum of the NCC-1701-D was shown in several episodes.**

---

The [**Arboretum**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Arboretum) on the Enterprise-D was located on Deck 17, Section 21-Alpha and was roughly three times the size of a standard holodeck. The arboretum was broken up into three sections - a hydroponics/botany lab, a greenhouse, and the main arboretum.

The lab and greenhouse are where [Keiko O'Brien](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Keiko_O%27Brien) spends most of her time, and she can be seen working in these areas several times. For example, she is working in the greenhouse section when [Data](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Data) approaches her during TNG S04E11 "[Data's Day](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Data%27s_Day_(episode))" at the request of [Miles O'Brien](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Miles_O%27Brien). The lab and greenhouse are located at opposite ends of the room, with the main Arboretum in the middle.

[image]

The main section of the Arboretum, which includes numerous plants and a small pond, is what most crew think of as "The Arboretum". It appears in numerous TNG episodes, most notably S05E22 "[Imaginary Friend](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Imaginary_Friend_(episode))" and S07E07 "[Dark Page](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Page_(episode))".

[image]

***Note:*** The fourth season episode "Data's Day" was the first appearance of both Keiko AND the Arboretum, as well as several other new sections of the ship - including the barbershop and the replicator center.

Comment: Heh -- I'm rewatching from the beginning and I'm on S05E20 so that explains it (I guess I missed it in S04E11.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - IIRC, it's when Keiko gets cold feet and Miles asks Data to go talk to her. She's working in the greenhouse part when her and Data are talking. It's located at the opposite end of the Arboretum as the lab.

Comment: I believe Data also visits the arboretum a second time to apologize to Keiko in the same episode.

Comment: http://old.trekipedia.com/images/library/tech/arboretum-tng-185.jpg

Comment: @TML - FYI, the word "Dúnadan" is the proper singular form of the word "Dúnedain".  If it ain't broke, don't fix it.  :)

Comment: Wrong question, but duly noted. :)

Answer (score 1):

It appears on-screen several times, first in [Data's Day](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Data's_Day_(episode)) and then later in both in [Imaginary Friend](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Imaginary_Friend_(episode)) and [Dark Page](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Page_(episode)).

Children  playing in Arboretum in *Imaginary Friend*
[image: Children playing in Arboretum]

The Troi women in Arboretum from *Dark Page* - (this appears to be the reverse angle of the previous shot)
[image: Troi women in Arboretum, Dark Page]

Comment: they aren't technically in the arboretum though. 1) it is all in Mother Troi's mind and 2) it is meant to be near a lake on Betazed

Answer (score 1):

There are several episodes of ST:TNG with scenes set in the arboretum. The one that comes to mind specifically is the episode Dark Page (season 7 episode 7) which is summarised [here](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Page_(episode)).